# Correct me, please, if I make mistake somewhere.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I have such a task: find the radius of convergence for series
$$\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{n\cdot3^{2n}\cdot x^{n}\cdot(1-x)^{n}}{2^{n}}$$
I use Cauchy-Hadamart theorem and do this $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left |\frac{n\cdot3^{2n} \cdot x^{n}\cdot (1-x)^{n}}{2^{n}}\right |}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left |\frac{n^{\frac1n} \,\cdot 3^{2}\, x\cdot(1-x)}{2}\right |$$
as $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac1n}=1$$
i have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left |\frac{n^{\frac1n} \, 3^{2}\, x(1-x)}{2}\right |=\lim{x\to\infty}\left |\frac{9x(1-x)}{2}\right|$$
and now:$$\left |\frac{9x(1-x)}{2}\right|< 1\Rightarrow \left |x(1-x)  \right |< \frac29 $$
After I solve this inequality I will get my radius?

Comment: Yes. Another way to get the radius of convergence would be to use the ratio test, which will give you the same inequality.

Comment: This is exactly the right way to determine (most of) the values of $x$ for which the series converges. However, I don't think "radius of convergence" is the right term here. A normal power series centered at $a$ always has an interval of convergence centered at $a$, and so the "radius" of that interval of convergence is a reasonable thing. However, in this case, the set of $x$ for which the series converges is not even an interval! so it doesn't make sense to me to ask about its radius of convergence.

Comment: For the variable $x$ you will not get a radius of convergence but an interval of convergence. Convergence occurs when $x\in (1/3,2/3),$ equivalently when $|x-1/2|<1/6.$ And divergence occurs when $|x-1/2|>1/6.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The opposite of what you write?